# Determine if cocoa app was started by the user or a cron/launchd job

Tags: cocoa, launchd

Is there a way for a Cocoa application to tell if it's being run interactively or from something like cron?  Basically I want to have the GUI appear if it's a person running the command, but if it's being called from something like cron, then I don't want the GUI to show.

Comment: Maybe you can implement `--nogui` argument

Comment: Sure, but I was hoping for a way for the app to determine this itself.

Comment: but you will remove the possibility to run your app with gui from script/terminal

Comment: If I manually run a script that calls this app, it would still see that it has a controlling TTY, and the GUI would appear like normal.  I'm looking for something similar to the "-t 0" check in perl.

Comment: Are you interested in whether you can have a GUI, or whether your app is being run from the Terminal? Running an app from the Finder will not give it a TTY, but it still should show a GUI.

Comment: Whether it can have a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for the [`isatty` function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/isatty.3.html) (which is probably what perl's `-t` test uses).

```
if (isatty(0)) {
    // standard input is a “tty” hence I should run interactively
}
```

Comment: When the application is started from the Finder, [that expression returns false](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HlB43.png). I asked the questioner for clarification in the comments on the question; it appears that the presence of a TTY specifically is not actually what they are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `launchctl list` command.

> With no arguments, list all of the jobs loaded into launchd